# Send objects over socket repeatedly

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to write a client-server application in which multiple clients can send objects containing updates to the server at any given time. So far, I managed to connect the clients to the server and send the first object, but I can't send objects at a later time (without making a new connection). This is my code:

Server:

```
ServerSocketChannel ssc = null;
try {
    ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    ssc.configureBlocking(true);

    while (true) {
        SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sc.socket().getInputStream());
        Object obj = ois.readObject();

        Client client = (Client)obj;                

        sc.close();
    }

} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

} finally {
    if (ssc != null) {
        try {
            ssc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
SocketChannel sc;
ObjectOutputStream oos;

try {
    sc = SocketChannel.open();
    sc.configureBlocking(true);

    sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(client.getPort()));

    try {
        /* While channel's socket is not connected */
        while (!sc.finishConnect()) {}
        /* Channel's socket is now connected */
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sc.socket().getOutputStream());
        sendClientObjectToServer();
    }
    catch (ConnectException e){}
} catch (IOException e) {}
finally {
    if (sc != null) {
        try {
            sc.close();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}

public void sendClientObjectToServer() {
    try {
        oos.writeObject(client);
    }
    catch (IOException e){}
}
```

The *sendClientObjectToServer* method works fine the first time, but I get a *ClosedChannelException* if I try to call it later (on the press of a jbutton).

**EDIT:** Found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997106/java-client-sever-app-while-on-objectinputstream-read-thread).

Comment: You need to have an open connection to the server every time you need to communicate with it. One option would be to not close the connection unless the application is closed.

Comment: `while (!sc.finishConnect()) {}` is an abomination unto the Lord. If you want blocking mode, why are you using non-blocking mode?

Answer (score 1):

You have to either keep the TCP connection alive, to be able to send an update later or you can use something like UDP (which also comes with its own problems, like packet loss or double receiving) but doesn't require a "connection" like TCP does.

This is your problem here:

```
    Client client = (Client)obj;                

    sc.close();
```

You're closing the connection on the client as soon as they connect.

Comment: Thanks, that was clearly a mistake. However, it doesn't solve my problem. Can you spot something else wrong?

Comment: Okay, so your server in your loop is accepting one connection, reading ONE object from the input stream and then moving onto the next connection. You'll need to thread your server or only accept one client on that thread if you want to receive multiple messages from the same client. Remember accept() is a blocking call too.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work anyway. You can't use streams over non-blocking socket channels. And I never understand why people connect in non-blocking mode and then write 'while (!sc.finishConnext()){}' loops like the above. You're just exchanging a nice clean blocking mechanism for a CPU-smoking spin mechanism. It's pointless. Do the connect and *then* go into non-blocking mode, or else do it properly and select on OP_CONNECT. But in this case you must throw it all away and use a Socket.

Comment: The code for connecting a Socket is 'new Socket(...)'. It's all in the Javadoc, and there is a very good Custom Networking tutorial.